# I need to update a multi-value picklist field with multiple values through workbench

Tags: workbench

I need to update a multi-value picklist field with multiple values through workbench. I have tried using semi-colon between the values but have received an error that "

> You May Only Select One Account Size Per Business Area. Please Revisit
>   The Values You Have Entered

". Can anyone help me?

```
ID                 Account_Size
001g000000ibzXU    RTD - A; RTD - C
```

Comment: there is some custom validation which are preventing. check that.

Answer (score 0):

The ; separator works for sure.

Sample Request body :

```
{
"attributes" : {
    "type" : "Account",
 "Id" : "0019000001dK6X2AAK"    
  },

"hobby__c" : "Chess;RC Cars"
}
```

Here is screen shot  that proved it works:
[image]

There are many possible reason that its showing this error.
for ex; Validation error (as commented by Tushar) or custom error from your apex